# how to execute shell commands from a specific directory?

Tags: grails, jobs

In grails to run a shell command is as easy as

```
"ls".execute().text
```

If i want to run the above shell command from the grails logs directory then how can i achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In grails to run a shell command from perticular directory.

"ls /badDir(give you log dir path grails logs )".execute().text

Comment: @user734861 please try abive command hope this will help you thank you

Comment: can you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39448016/how-to-access-a-file-inside-logs-directory-from-grails-application ?

Comment: this is not working for me. looks like the execute command doesnt like spaces.

Answer (score 0):

if the command you want to execute is something different than a typical bash command (where you can avoid the need to modify the working directory by passing the path as a parameter):

I have many cases where I need to execute external binaries and in most of the cases I end up using good old ProcessBuilder:

```
new java.lang.ProcessBuilder('ls', '-l').directory(new File('/some/path')).start().text
```

additionally, escaping spaces/quotes/etc in strings can be painful.
with processBuilder, as you can build up a list of strings describing your command, and then just run it.

```
def cmd = ['some_command']
cmd << userInputVariable  // does not matter if it contains spaces, quotes, backslashes or anything
println new ProcessBuilder(cmd).directory(someDirectory).start().text
```