# how to access a file inside logs directory from grails application?

Tags: grails, jobs

I am simply trying to print the content of the latest log file inside the logs directory from Grails. command.execute().text is returning empty. so I must be doing something wrong. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

```
def command = "cat \$(ls logs/localhost_access_log* | tail -1)"     

println command.execute().text
```

Comment: why are defining * and tail -1

Comment: i am listing all files with the prefix localhost_access_log and then i am printing the last file.

Comment: before driving a ferrari the wheel must be invented :) def command = "ls logs" (aka the wheels first) what does that say - any logs listed

Answer (score 0):

`ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getRealPath('/')` will kind of help although thats the pah to the running app. You may need to do

some verification of path before attempting to get logs (untested)

```
path=ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getRealPath('/')
println "--- path is ${path}"
command = "cd $path && cat \$(ls ../logs/localhost_access_log* | tail -1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of making a complex cmdline string, why not just program it with the groovy/java tools?

```
// find real directory of logs folder
def dir = new File(ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getRealPath('logs'))
// inside logs folder look for newest file beginning with "localhost_access"
def file = dir.listFiles({ name -> name.startsWith('localhost_access') } as FilenameFilter).max({ it.lastModified() })
def content = null
if (file) {
    // read content directly
    def content = file.text
    // or via a process
    def content = new ProcessBuilder('cat', file.absolutePath).start().text
}
```